# How to define $ionicLoading scope?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am having problems controlling a [ion-slides](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlides/) directive inside an `$ionicLoading` directive launched on `$rootScope` (it is like a tour). I need to change the sliders with two buttons.

I do not know how to define correctly the scope here:

```
$ionicLoading.show({
    templateUrl: 'js/_tour/intro.html',
});
```

I want to define functions there to control the `$ionicSlideBoxDelegate`

I tried something like:

```
$ionicLoading.show({
    templateUrl: 'js/_tour/intro.html',
        scope: {
                something: function(){console.log(something);}
                }
    });
```

but it gives me this error:

> ionic.bundle.js:21162 TypeError: scope.$new is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `scope` parameter expects to be supplied with a *scope*, not a hash.

Try this instead:

```
var scope = $rootScope.$new();
scope.something = function() { console.log( "foo" ); }
```

Comment: Thanks, sadly I still have problems controlling the ion-slider but the scope now works.